# Can you characterize a vector field $v$ with uniform curl as $v(x) = a + b \times x$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, cross-product, curl

Let $v:\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$ a vector field such that $\forall x\in\mathbb R^3, (\nabla \times v) (x) = \rho~$ where $\rho$ is a constant. [Example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tus1V.png).

**Can you characterize $v$ simply?**

**What I have so far:**

If I'm not mistaken, a vector field of the form $x \mapsto a + b \times x$ has a curl of $2b$ (with $a,b\in\mathbb R^3$ and $\times$ the cross-product). Is this the only form of vector field with uniform curl?

As far as I understand the curl of $v$ being uniform is equivalent to the antisymmetric part of the Jacobian of $v$ being uniform. If the symmetric part of the Jacobian of $v$ is zero, then we would thus have $J_v(x)x = Bx = b\times x$ for some antisymmetric matrix $B$, which might be part of the answer.

Is there a reason to think the symmetric part is equal to zero? This would mean that $\nabla \cdot v=0$ right?

Comment: Instead of "uniform," you should say "constant." :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you could add to your $v$ any irrotational vector field, i.e. $w$ with $\nabla \times w = 0$.  In particular, $w$ could be the gradient of any twice differentiable function, since
$\nabla \times \nabla f = 0$.

Comment: I see thank you, and how about the other part (with nonzero curl), is it necessarily of the form $b \times x$ ?

Comment: @Geert-Jan Like the answer said, if you add a curl-$0$ field to a curl-$\rho$ field you get another curl-$\rho$ field. Thus, if you add a nonzero irrotational field to the field $b\times x$ you will get another field that is not of the form $b\times x$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What I should have asked instead is this: can you decompose any field $v$ with uniform curl as the sum of a curl-free field and a field of the form $b \times x$?

Comment: Yes, because curl is a linear operator.  If $u$ and $v$ are fields with $\nabla \times u = \nabla \times v$, then $u = v + (u-v)$ with $\nabla \times (u - v) = \nabla \times u - \nabla \times v = 0$.